# "code EMISSINGARG" error when running rpm install

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, npm-install, nvm

I am trying to run nom install on a Node project in Mac (macOS Big Sur 11.2). I get the following error. I installed node using rpm like this:

```
$ brew install nvm
$ nvm install 6.4.0
$ nvm alias default 6.4.0
```

I have retried this step after completely removing all node/node_module files too. Still the error happens.

```
npm install
npm ERR! Darwin 20.3.0
npm ERR! argv "/Users/shankar/.nvm/versions/node/v6.4.0/bin/node" "/Users/shankar/.nvm/versions/node/v6.4.0/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v6.4.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.3
npm ERR! code EMISSINGARG

npm ERR! typeerror Error: Missing required argument #1
npm ERR! typeerror     at andLogAndFinish (/Users/shankar/.nvm/versions/node/v6.4.0/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:31:3)
npm ERR! typeerror     at fetchPackageMetadata (/Users/shankar/.nvm/versions/node/v6.4.0/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:51:22)
npm ERR! typeerror     at resolveWithNewModule (/Users/shankar/.nvm/versions/node/v6.4.0/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:515:12)
npm ERR! typeerror     at /Users/shankar/.nvm/versions/node/v6.4.0/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:516:7
npm ERR! typeerror     at /Users/shankar/.nvm/versions/node/v6.4.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/iferr/index.js:13:50
npm ERR! typeerror     at /Users/shankar/.nvm/versions/node/v6.4.0/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:37:12
npm ERR! typeerror     at addRequestedAndFinish (/Users/shankar/.nvm/versions/node/v6.4.0/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:67:5)
npm ERR! typeerror     at returnAndAddMetadata (/Users/shankar/.nvm/versions/node/v6.4.0/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:121:7)
npm ERR! typeerror     at pickVersionFromRegistryDocument (/Users/shankar/.nvm/versions/node/v6.4.0/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:138:20)
npm ERR! typeerror     at /Users/shankar/.nvm/versions/node/v6.4.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/iferr/index.js:13:50
npm ERR! typeerror This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR! typeerror     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
```

What could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NVM is not a NPM version manager, instead it manages Node version.

nvm alias default 6.4.0 means you will use node v6.4.0 as default node version, as it says in error message,

> ```
> npm ERR! node v6.4.0
> npm ERR! npm  v3.10.3
> ```

which is more than 5 years old.

Using the latest version of node should resolve the issue, v12 or 14 is recommended.

Docs here: https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm